# Get list of commits between two revisions in AWS CodeCommit

Tags: aws-sdk, aws-codecommit

How can I get a list of all commits between two revisions in AWS CodeCommit, using the SDK or AWS CLI?

Essentially, what I need is an AWS CodeCommit way to `git log a..b`

There's a `batch-get-commits` method, but that requires a list with all the commit ids.

Answer (score 1):

If you call `getCommit`, there is a `parents` field in the response, which you can use to retreive the previous commit.

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const codecommit = new AWS.CodeCommit()

const commitIdFrom = 'commit hash'
const commitIdTo = 'commit hash'
const repositoryName = 'your repo name'

let keepRetrievingCommits = true
let commitId = commitIdTo

const commits = []
while (keepRetrievingCommits) {
    try {
        const params = { commitId, repositoryName }
        const ccData = await codecommit.getCommit(params).promise()

        const { author, message, parents } = ccData.commit

        commits.push({
            repositoryName,
            commitId,
            author: author.email,
            message
        })

        if(parents.length === 1) {
            commitId = parents[0]
        }
        else {
            keepRetrievingCommits = false
        }

        if(commitId === commitIdFrom) { // won't include info of 'commitFrom'
            keepRetrievingCommits = false
        }
    } catch(err) {
        console.error(`Error while getting commit details ${commitId} on repo ${repositoryName}: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`)
    }
}

// commitsData.forEach(...)
```

Comment: awesomesauce. Worked perfectly.
And if you need the most recent commitId you can get it from `getBranch`